# why super+a why not only super key

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

in ubuntu 18.04 
to go to dash menue we have to press superkey+a.
before it was just superkey.
and there is a search app bar in dash menu.
So why super+a why not only super key

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges, before it was Unity, not it is GNOME. Two different things.

Comment: Ya, but the second one is more energy eficient. it may be saving atleast a nanoteta calories per press. which could be used to do something constructive.

Comment: It's not that <Super> doesn't do anything at all. <Super> key performs a different role in GNOME, doesn't it? Also you can simply search for apps (and other stuffs) and launch them after pressing only <Super>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, <kbd>Super</kbd> is defined to show you the overview of running windows and your desktops that are in use. Gnome Developpers consider the Activities overview as the most central place to control your workflow.

- You see and can switch between running windows;
- You can quickly launch your frequently used apps from the dock on the left;
- You can launch a less frequently used application just by typing part of the name, or moving to the Application menu;
- You have an overview of your workspaces on the right and can move to them to look into more detail.

All this from a space you quickly can reach with a press on <kbd>Super</kbd>

If you would prefer that <kbd>Super</kbd> directly opens the application menu (which you can open directly with the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> keyboard combination), then you can install the extension [Show Applications instead of Overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1337/show-applications-instead-of-overview/). You can then still open the activities overview with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

This extension will cause the Applications overview to appear when you press and release <kbd>Super</kbd> alone. The <kbd>Esc</kbd> will by default first bring you to your application overview, which may be unexpected and not what you wish. To have the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key bring you directly to your desktop again, you can install an additional extension, [ESC to close overview from applications list](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1122/esc-to-close-overview-from-applications-list/).

Comment: This answer says how to set <Super> to open "Show Applications" instead of "Activities" overview, but **does not answer** OP's question "**why** super+a **why not** only super key"! :-p Joking aside, nice one.

Comment: @pomsky: Some part of the "why" is there: because it is by default defined differently. Indeed , I could also venture in conceptual reasons why Gnome decided this way, but I consider it too risky ;)